# how to do a Testing on an Already Installed Android application using Appium + Selenium ?

Tags: appium

is there any way to test an application which is **already** installed For Eg. i want to test the **calculator** or **google map** application ?

my Current Appium version is 1.3.4.1

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you could do it. Here is sample approach to accomplish it.

**1. First, get the application package name**

To get the application package name, use:

```
adb shell 'pm list package -f' |grep calculator
```

note the APK file and the package name. For example:

```
package:/system/app/SecCalculator2/SecCalculator2.apk=com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator
```

the apk file is **/system/app/SecCalculator2/SecCalculator2.apk** and the package name is: **com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator**

---

**2. Get the launch-able Activity name**

First, pull the application APK's from devices:

```
adb pull /system/app/SecCalculator2/SecCalculator2.apk
```

then use **aapt** to get the launchable Activity name:

```
 aapt dump badging SecCalculator2.apk
```

Look for **launchable-activity** in the results, or use grep to filter it. The result should be similar like this:

```
 launchable-activity: name='com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator'  label='Calculator' icon=''
```

On these sample, the launchable activity name is: **.Calculator**

---

**3. Now, create the DesiredCapabilities**

create your desired capability to launch the installed applications. Make sure to match the **appPackage** and **appActivity** from the steps above. (this sample is using java).

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "ANDROID");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "S5");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator"); 
    cap.setCapability("appActivity",".Calculator");  
    cap.setCapability("noSign", true);
```

And then, just create the test scripts and automate it.

Answer (score 2):

TO know the activity name and package name of any apps simply download a apkinfo apps from playstore and get the imformation about the apk. and set to the capabilities and run your apps.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answer - could you please edit your answer to explain how this solves their problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install apk info application from Play Store and check appPackage and appActivity information, then set the same in desired capabilities:

```
  caps["deviceName"] = "Device Emulator"
    caps["platformVersion"] = "8.1"
    caps["platformName"] = "android"
    caps["appPackage"]= "<package>"
    caps["appActivity"] = "<activity>"
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", caps)
```